# Inserting vlookup function via vba adds brackets on column

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a problem with brackets in complex vlookup "insert function".
It's needed for a plan for each day of week. Because of slow performance of workbook I decided to turn on/off each day of plan, entire plan works but the column with expeditions. Code for part of "U" column is:

```
Range(Cells(firstm, "U"), Cells(lastm, "U")) = "=IF(RC2=0,IF(RC[-8]>0,
IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(G:G,Expedition!F:H,3,0)),R1C22,VLOOKUP(G:G,Expedition!F:H,3,0)),R1C22)
,IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(G:G,Expedition!F:H,3,0)),R1C22,VLOOKUP(G:G,Expedition!F:H,3,0)))"
```

It's quite messy, but it works :) at least in sheet.

The problem is that part of inserted formula in cell is

```
VLOOKUP(G:(G);Expedition!F:(H);3;0)
```

instead of

```
VLOOKUP(G:G;Expedition!F:H;3;0)
```

if only VLOOKUP is used, it works fine, I have no idea why in this example are those brackets.

Any ideas?

//edited for better understanding

Comment: What do you mean by "that result of VLOOKUP is"? Is that what is put into your cell?

Comment: ah, sorry.. that was written badly. Result of that insert, not vlookup itself. Result of VLOOKUP is date of order from Expedition sheet

Comment: If you delete the redundant brackets, does the result change?

Comment: It works, but I would need to delete brackets in each cell in ~1500 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use either `R1C1` or `A1` reference style and specify the formula type, for example:

```
Range(Cells(firstm, "U"), Cells(lastm, "U")).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC2=0,IF(RC[-8]>0, IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(C[7],Expedition!C[6]:C[8],3,0)),R1C22,VLOOKUP(C[7],Expedition!C[6]:C[8],3,0)),R1C22) ,IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(C[7],Expedition!C[6]:C[8],3,0)),R1C22,VLOOKUP(C[7],Expedition!C[6]:C[8],3,0)))"
```

edit: of course the relative references `G:G` etc have to be changed to relative references `C[7]`. `C[7]` becomes `G:G` while `C7` becomes `$G:$G`.

Comment: The problem is that I need to insert this formula into ~1500 cells, each of them looks up in sheet with ~400 rows(dynamic size), so i would prefer this: VLOOKUP(G:G;Expedition!F:H;3;0)

Comment: I'll change it, just a sec

Answer (score 0):

Well, it perfectly works.. when I'm using that in half of the code, why haven't I used that for columns?.. :) Thank you!